# Identifying a SMD component

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have problem with identifying a SMD component. This component is a part of automotive module. It has 2 pins. One of the pins is attached to Vcc 12 V, and the other is attached to the circuit parallel with a capacitor.

I have tested it and has any continuity. So I assume this part is broken. On this part there is written `ST E CH C632`.

Can any one help me to identify this part?

[image]

Comment: That is the ST Micro logo; I suggest looking around the ST micro site.

Comment: Its probably a [ST Transil SMAJ28CA](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ff/c0/80/cc/19/4c/45/af/CD00001333.pdf/files/CD00001333.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001333.pdf) bidirectional 28V TVS diode. And measuring it with a multimeter will tell you nothing (if it's good).

Comment: Measuring in circuit won't tell you much.  If you knew the surrounding circuitry you might get some use out of measruing it in place.  Take it out and measure it.  See if your "short" still exists if you take that part out.